# Cordova - Crosswalk armeabi-v7a and arm64-v8a publish error

Tags: cordova, publish, crosswalk, phonegap

I have a problem when i try to publish a cordova with crosswalk plugin.
I generate 4 versions with the following sentences:

```
cordova build android --release
cordova build android --gradleArg=-PcdvBuildArch=arm --xwalk64bit --release
```

This sentences generate 4 versiones (arm7, arm64, x86 and x86_64 apk's).

When i upload the versions an try to publish i have and error said that the arm64 replaces the arm7.

> Se ha sustituido el APK por completo
>   PROBLEMA
>   Ningún usuario podrá ver este APK porque uno o varios APK con códigos de versión superiores lo han sustituido por completo.
>   RESOLUCIÓN
>   Retira este APK de la versión o revisa los códigos de versión y segmentación de los APK incluidos en esta versión."

How i can solve this? Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that the androidCode version of x86 and arm7 versions must be less than the x86_64 and arm64 versions:
amr7 --> 1001 arm64 --> 1020, x86 -->  1010, x86_63 -->  1030